# How can I speed up Crystal Reports 11 printing?

Tags: performance, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports 11 (and VB6) to open a report file, load the data from an Access database and either print the report to a printer or export the report to another .rpt file (for later printing without the database)

Even for small amounts of data the process is somewhat slow. Profiling showed about 1.5 seconds for three records (one page) For about 500 records on 10 pages, it's 1.7 seconds.

Can I do something the speed it up? Can I tweak the data or the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an idea, but I 'd first try to build a view on the server, so that CR can directly access the report's data without dealing with any join or filter or whatever on the user's side. I have read terrible things about CR querying the server multiple times with the same query before displaying the report ...

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that there are no other replies I'll just post what I'm really thinking and that is honestly I wish my Crystal Reports 11 app was as fast as yours.  In my application there are so many suppressed fields and sections that Crystal just drags for about a minute to generate any report.